# DropDownList Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList that populates its values through an OnInit method. It uses a HiddenField and queries a database to populate itself like so:

```
protected void DropDown_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string value = Page.Request[choice.UniqueID] == null ? choice.Value : Page.Request[choice.UniqueID].ToString();
        PricingModelDataContext ctx = new PricingModelDataContext();
        var list = from p in ctx.servers
                   where p.server_type == (((from a in ctx.server_types
                                             where a.name == value
                                             select new { a.id }).Single()).id)
                   && p.isActive.Value
                   select p;
        DropDownList dList = sender as DropDownList;
        dList.Items.Clear();
        dList.Items.Add("");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            dList.Items.Add(item.name);
        }

    }
    catch { }
}
```

Everthing works fine until I click a button that auto populates the values temporarily like so:

```
DropDown_Init(DropDown, e);
DropDown.SelectedValue = "Set Value";
```

Now, whenever the page reloads the DropDownList, the values won't change (they still contain the original values triggered from the button click).

Why does this behaviour occur? Is there a way around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if the DDL init method is getting hit again? It sounds like it isn't.

Comment: Any reason why you are binding in Init and not Load?

Comment: Please confirm if code is not throwing any exception, your code is silently suppressing any possible exception.

Comment: This might be because your values are always overwriten with a post back. You might need to wrap your logic in a `if(!IsPostBack)`

Comment: It is getting hit again and there is no error being thrown. The values will update during the OnInit, but, by the time the page gets to load, reverts back to the old values.

Comment: I'm binding in Init to reduce the ViewState since the project is heavy on ViewState and there are a lot of values being added during the query,

Comment: Is the ViewState disabled for the control then? If it isn't then the values could be getting overwritten.

Comment: Oh, by the way, your nested linq query does not need to be nested. It would speed things up if you made it its own statement.

Comment: No it isn't disabled. But how can it get overwritten? Wouldn't the new values be set during the OnInit method? Why does it retain values added to it during the event execution? Seems strange to me :S, especially since this happens way after the button is clicked (a few postbacks later)

Comment: If you don't want this behavior, simply set `EnableViewState=false` in the DropDownList. That way when another button is clicked that forces the page to post back, the control resets to the original empty state.

Comment: @Icarus but the problem with that is that I cannot retrieve the value the user selected when they post the values back to the server.

Comment: You could, if you get it from the Request Collection as so: var value = `Request.Params[dropDown.ClientID]`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The solution is to basically populate the values in Page_Load, to use !IsPostBack so it's only populated once, and to call it whenever the values need to be changed during run-time.

This is following the points mentioned by Cam Bruce and gunr2171.

Thank you so much everyone for the help!